# How to avoid multiple versions of Gradle being used when importing Android projects from GitHub and only use one Single version of Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[Gradle on Hard Disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jroqA.png)

How to avoid multiple versions of Gradle being used when importing Android projects from GitHub and only use one Single version of Gradle to save hard disk space?

I have low hard disk space. When importing Gradle Android projects from GitHub, many have different versions of Gradle specified.

Preferably, how to make sure when importing any kind of Gradle Android project, only one single version specified by me (which would be latest) is used.

So even if the GitHub project specified version 6.7 and I specified in some settings 6.8, then 6.8 should be used regardless.

Too much data and space are wasted otherwise.

Comment: You should ignore `gradle-wrapper.properties` in your project's gitIgnore so when you clone a repository it won't change the version you have once specified. I think it should do the trick

Comment: When you import the project, change it to the version you want. "Too much data and space are wasted" Really? the sum of all those gradle versions is less than 100 megabytes of data. Your Transforms-1 and -2 folders are almost 1 GB (cache). So.. what is the real issue here? You can go ahead and delete them if you don't want them, just know that if you don't remove it from your project, gradle will download them again.

Answer (score 0):

In git, the uploader has added all the Gradle files installed in his system. If you want to remove it. You need to edit gitignore file so that the git doesn't upload everything.

It's very simple. You just need to add

```
# Gradle files
.gradle/
```

in .gitignore file check here!

https://github.com/xabhi7549/ImageSliderExampleInKotlin/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: hey... @Henry, I have updated my answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To "avoid using multiple versions", before importing a project into android studio, right after you clone it, check its `.gradle` files for the project, and make sure the `distributionUrl` is the version of gradle you want.

For the actual version of Gradle, check our `gradle-wrapper.properties` for something like:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

That's the version of "Gradle" that will be downloaded if you don't already have it. (the `-all` version is 139mb).

I think you're chasing the wrong problem here; this whole post and process will gain you at the most <200mb of HDD space. An average project will likely use much more than that to build (as cache).

You're still welcome to go to your `$HOME/.gradle` folder and clear up its `/cache/` folder (warning: you'll need to re-download all dependencies again).

You can also save space by deleting the Gradle caches. If you want to learn more about how they work, check [this blog post](https://jasonatwood.io/archives/1966) titled: "Understanding Gradle caches" (two parts).